# Postgres error when parsing date with timezone

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a bunch of records, with different values for a date and I need them all parsed as a date value, so I'm trying to parse a date in postgres and I'm receiving an error which doesn't tell me much

```sql
select to_Date(:original_date, 'YYYYmmDD');
```

When I pass this value to `original_date` is when I get the error: `'2022-11-18T11:02:08-03:00'`

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2022-11-18T11:02:08-03:00"
  Where: SQL statement "select to_Date(original_date, 'YYYYmmDD')"
PL/pgSQL function parse_date(character varying) line 5 at SQL statement
```

Comment: Shouldn't your format string then be yyyy-mm-dd?  It looks like you left out the hyphens.  Also, for what it's worth, if your date is already a date in the native system, omit the to_date and use native datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Hambone in the comment below the question, changing my date format to `'YYYY-mm-DD'` works like a charm.

Thanks for that Hambone!